# Setting multiple map point icons in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile

I am trying to populate some map points on a canvas which have been read from a JSON file.

I can create one set of points fine but I want to add different icons depending on what kind of point it is. I have tried evaluating the JSON data the map will not load with more than on kind of icon.

My code is as follows:

```
$.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 


                        if (marker.company == "Capgemini") {
                            'icon':new google.maps.MarkerImage("capico.png"),

                        } else if (marker.company == "Accenture") {
                            'icon':new google.maps.MarkerImage("accico.png"),

                        }

                    'bounds': true 
                }).click(function() {
                    //$('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 
                    //  'content': marker.content 
                        $.mobile.changePage("#details");
```

Not sure where im going wrong here.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var customIcons = {
      "Capgemini": {
        icon: 'path_to_your_marker_pictures/capico.png',
      },      
      "Accenture": {
        icon: 'path_to_your_marker_pictures/accico.png',
      }
    };

var icon = customIcons[marker.company] || {};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: point,
     icon: icon.icon,
    });
```

Best,
Darko

Comment: Thanks for the answer Darko but I dont understand your code. Depending on the marker.company I need to set the type of icon so this needs to be in an if statement.

Comment: I edit the code in my answer (look above). I adapt my code base on your example, hope you understand now.

Comment: @EHarpham - You don't actually need an `if` statement. DarkoJ's answer does the same thing by looking up `category` in the `customIcons` object and selecting one of the two icons there. You would use `marker.company` instead of `category`.

Comment: I also now edit in my code `category` to `marker.company`, so hope that is now everything is clear to EHarpham (look above in my answer).